# Callback fires earlier than it should (Mean stack)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, mean-stack

I have two functions getCharacterInfo(callback) and apply(). I am calling apply() as a callback in getCharacterInfo, but apply (the callback) fires earlier than it should (at least from what I can tell from the code)

This is my code:

getCharacterInfo(callback)

```
$scope.getCharacterInfo = function(callback) {
    temp = $http.get('https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/character/' + $rootScope.current_user_realm + '/' + $rootScope.current_user + '?locale=en_GB&apikey=hidden');
    temp.then(function onSuccess(response){
        $scope.charInfo = response.data;
        $scope.charInfo.thumbnail = "https://render-api-eu.worldofwarcraft.com/static-render/eu/" + response.data.thumbnail
        console.log("$scope.charinfo = " + $scope.charInfo)
        console.log("response.data = " + response.data)
        if(callback) {
            callback();
        }
    })
}
```

apply()

```
$scope.apply = function() {
            $scope.newApplication.charName = $scope.charInfo.name;
            $scope.newApplication.realm = $scope.charInfo.realm;
            $scope.newApplication.armoryLink = 'http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/'+ $scope.charInfo.realm + '/'+ $scope.charInfo.name +'/advanced'
            console.log($scope.newApplication)
            applicationsService.save($scope.newApplication, function(){
                $scope.applications = applicationsService.query();
                $scope.newApplication = null;
            });
    };
```

The function call is made from an HTML-submit form

```
<form ng-Submit="getCharacterInfo(apply())">
```

The error I am getting is in apply(), where the console tells me that $scope.charInfo is undefined. Also the console.log()'s in characterInfo are never fired, which I think they should?

What is it I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `apply` argument without the parentheses:

```
<form ng-submit="getCharacterInfo(apply)">
```

Otherwise, the function `apply` gets executed first, then its result is passed to the `getCharacterInfo` function.

Comment: It worked, thank you kind sir for sparing me from headache!